# Comparing three data frames to evaluate multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes:

- ob (Orderbook) - an orderbook containing Part Numbers, the week they are due and the hours it takes to build them.

  | Part Number | Due Week | Build Hours |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | A | 2022-46 | 4 |
  | A | 2022-46 | 5 |
  | B | 2022-46 | 8 |
  | C | 2022-47 | 1.6 |
- osm (Operator Skill Matrix) - a skills matrix containing operators names and part numbers

  | Operator | Part number |
  | --- | --- |
  | Mr.One | A |
  | Mr.One | B |
  | Mr.Two | A |
  | Mr.Two | B |
  | Mrs. Three | C |
- ah (Avaliable Hours) - a list containg how many hours an operator can work in a given week

  | Operator | YYYYWW | Hours |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | Mr.One | 2022-45 | 40 |
  | Mr.One | 2022-46 | 35 |
  | Mr.Two | 2022-46 | 37 |
  | Mr.Two | 2022-47 | 39 |
  | Mrs. Three | 2022-47 | 40 |
  | Mrs. Three | 2022-48 | 45 |

I am trying to work out for each week if there are enough operators, with the right skills, working enough hours to complete all of the orders on the orderbook. And if not, identify the orders that cant be complete.

Step by Step it would look like this:

1. Take the part number of the first row of the orderbook.
2. Seach the skills matrix to find a list of operators who can build that part.
3. Seach the hours list and check if the operators have any hours avaliable for the week the order is due.
4. If the operator has hours avalible, add their name to that row of the orderbook.
5. Subtract the Build hours in the orderbook from the Avalible hours in the Avalible Hours df.
6. Repeat this for each row in the orderbook until all orders have a name against them or there are no avalible hours left.

The only thing i could think to try was a bunch of nested for loops, but as there are thousands of rows it takes ~45 minutes to complete one iteration and would  take days if not weeks to complete the whole thing.

```
#for each row in the orderbook
for i, rowi in ob_sum_hours.iterrows():
    #for each row in the operator skill matrix
    for j, rowj in osm.iterrows():
        #for each row in the avalible operator hours
        for y, rowy in aoh.iterrows():
            if(rowi['Material']==rowj['MATERIAL'] and rowi['ProdYYYYWW']==rowy['YYYYWW'] and rowj['Operator']==rowy['Operator'] and rowy['Hours'] > 0):`
        rowy['Hours'] -=rowi['PlanHrs']
        rowi['HoursAllocated'] = rowi['Operator']
```

The final result would look like this:

| Part Number | Due Week | Build Hours | Operator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-46 | 4 | Mr.One |
| A | 2022-46 | 5 | Mr.One |
| B | 2022-46 | 8 | Mr.Two |
| C | 2022-47 | 1.6 | Mrs.Three |

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are Mr. One and Mr. Two assigned to the first three rows in your expected output? In the `ah` dataframe they are not listed for that due week (2022-46)? Also, Mr. Two cannot build part C according to `osm` frame.

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same. Week 46 in general doesn't appear in `ah` at all, is that due to bad example or are there just weeks where no Operator is available.

Comment: Based on all the frames I believe the expected output should be `C,2022-47,1.6,Mrs. Three`

Comment: Sorry bad example, I have updated this to make it clearer.

Comment: @jhew123 thanks for updating but Mr. Two cannot build part C. Why is Mr. Two in your expected output for Part C?

Comment: @It_is_Chris - missed that one, i've changed it now.

Comment: I think your example still doesn't fit to the different tasks you got to fulfill. 1) From what I understand your desired output would also be correct if `Mr.One` takes on part `B` and `Mr.Two` takes on both part `A`, or even mixed. Both have more hours left and both skills for both parts. What's the rule there, how do we choose? 2) Also in your example with its desired output we can't see the scenario where used hours for one Operator are exhausted.

Comment: Instead of iterating through the dataframe which is notoriously slow you should investigate using `groupby` operations. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html The `itertools.combinations` function could also prove useful. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: @jhew123 added an option without a loop. But, you need to check. It is also interesting in practical terms how long both options will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made with one loop + apply on each line.

Orderbook.groupby(Orderbook.index) groups by index, i.e. my_func iterates through each row, still better than a loop.

In the 'aaa' list, we get a list of [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html?highlight=unique#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique) Operators that match. In the 'bbb' list, filter Avaliable by: 'YYYYWW', 'Operator' (using [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for the list of unique Operators) and 'Hours' greater than 0. Further in the loop, using the 'bbb' indices, we check free time and if 'ava' is greater than zero, using explicit indexing [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) set values.

```
import pandas as pd

Orderbook = pd.read_csv('Orderbook.csv', header=0)
Operator = pd.read_csv('Operator.csv', header=0)
Avaliable= pd.read_csv('Avaliable.csv', header=0)

Orderbook['Operator'] = 'no'


def my_func(x):
    aaa = Operator.loc[Operator['Part number'] == x['Part Number'].values[0], 'Operator'].unique()
    bbb = Avaliable[(Avaliable['YYYYWW'] == x['Due Week'].values[0]) &
                    (Avaliable['Operator'].isin(aaa)) & (Avaliable['Hours'] > 0)]

    for i in bbb.index:
        ava = Avaliable.loc[i, 'Hours'] - x['Build Hours'].values
        if ava >= 0:
            Avaliable.loc[i, 'Hours'] = ava
            Orderbook.loc[x.index, 'Operator'] = Avaliable.loc[i, 'Operator']
            break# added loop interrupt


Orderbook.groupby(Orderbook.index).apply(my_func)

print(Orderbook)
print(Avaliable)
```

**Update 18.11.2022**
I did it without cycles. But, you need to check. If you find something incorrect please let me know. You can also measure the exact processing time by putting at the beginning:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

and printing the elapsed time at the end:

```
time_ = datetime.datetime.now() - now
print('elapsed time', time_)
```

the code:

```
Orderbook = pd.read_csv('Orderbook.csv', header=0)
Operator = pd.read_csv('Operator.csv', header=0)
Avaliable = pd.read_csv('Avaliable.csv', header=0)

Orderbook['Operator'] = 'no'

aaa = [Operator.loc[Operator['Part number'] == Orderbook.loc[i, 'Part Number'], 'Operator'].unique() for i in
       range(len(Orderbook))]


def my_func(x):
    bbb = Avaliable[(Avaliable['YYYYWW'] == x['Due Week'].values[0]) &
                    (Avaliable['Operator'].isin(aaa[x.index[0]])) & (Avaliable['Hours'] > 0)]

    fff = Avaliable.loc[bbb.index, 'Hours'] - x['Build Hours'].values
    ind = fff[fff.ge(0)].index
    Avaliable.loc[ind[0], 'Hours'] = fff[ind[0]]
    Orderbook.loc[x.index, 'Operator'] = Avaliable.loc[ind[0], 'Operator']


Orderbook.groupby(Orderbook.index).apply(my_func)

print(Orderbook)
print(Avaliable)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tested this with my data and it has worked exactly as needed. Am I correct in thinking that it iterates through the Orderbook top to bottom? So that if I wanted to rank the orderbook in future I could sort by another column before running this code.

Comment: Yes, everything is correct starting from the first line of the Orderbook. You can test this by putting my_func inside the function: print('index', x.index, 'Operator', Orderbook.loc[x.index, 'Operator'].values). The function iterates over each line. I'm wondering how long the whole calculation was made?

Comment: Thanks. I ran this with ~5000 rows in the orderbook, ~12000 in the operator and ~600 rows in available which took around 30 seconds to complete. The orderbook and available data sets are limited to just the next three weeks currently however, this will expand to 20 weeks when live.

Comment: Do not leave. I found something (it takes a few minutes).

Comment: Added an interruption of the **break** loop, since a single operation is needed: if ava >= 0:. Without it, the subtraction happens multiple times. Check again. Check by: Avaliable.

Comment: I gave this a go and it returns this error: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Does the error occur in the variant without a loop or the first variant and which line is giving the error in the code?